# How can i remove Ubuntu from my PC?

Tags: 11.10

I'm someone who installed Ubuntu 11.10 on his computer and erased w7. Now I want to erase it and I don't know how... someone who could explain me in simple terms, step by step!!! THANKS. I also searched elsewhere but explanations are not good, they skip steps or are too risky

---

Soy un boludo que instalo el ubuntu 11.10 en su computadora y borre el w7. Ahora, lo que quiero es borrarlo y no se como... Alguien que sepa explicarme en terminos sinples, pasooo pooor pasooo!!! GRACIAS.
Busque en otros lados pero no te lo explican bien, se comen pasos o son muy riesgosos

Comment: Borraste el W7 por completo? Si borras el Ubuntu y no tienes tus discos de W7 no podrás usar la computadora.

Answer (score 1):

Information provided here: https://askubuntu.com/a/31417/9598 can be useful for erasing all the information in your hard disk drive, which can be done via Live Session.

Reproduced  here for your convenience:

> Take a look at this:
>   [How to clean a hard drive before reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27034/how-to-clean-a-hard-drive-before-reinstall/27040#27040)
>
> Placed here for your convenience:
>
> > If you refer to a fresh reinstall,
> >     when reinstalling you will find
> >     several options for the usage of your
> >     hard disk drive, which includes but
> >     not limits to:
> >
> > "Side by Side" install, which will
> >     install your new OS sharing the hard
> >     disk drive but without losing your
> >     current installation. This way, GRUB
> >     will be updated or installed as
> >     required.
> >
> > "Use the entire disk" which will
> >     physically erase the whole disk in
> >     order to use all its space for the new
> >     OS install.
> >
> > If what you wish is to use the hard
> >     disk drive for a data tasks such as
> >     BackUp or other data handling, you can
> >
> > > achieve that by first erasing the
> > >       whole partition and do it from
> > >       scratch. Formatting the disk will also
> > >       do the trick.
> >
> > Several tools will help you to achieve
> >     this task in Linux and other OS's.
> >
> > In Maverick, under
> >     "system/administration" you will find
> >     a "Disk Utility", inside of which you
> >     will find a disk drive and other
> >     devices tree on the left and its
> >     characteristics and tool list in the
> >     right side, where you can find both
> >     "Delete Partition" and "Format Drive"
> >     options.
> >
> > ### You can do this from a Live Session.
> >
> > *A screenshot is placed here for your convenience.*
>
> [image]
>
> Addittionally, take in consideration that some wireless devices has
>   stopped working as a part of an update from Maverick. That's my case
>   with a Compaq Presario V3000 (V3617LA) which wireless isn't working
>   anymore even with all my efforts and all the web/forums tricks.
>
> Good Luck!

Be aware that this procedure will delete ALL the data, including operating system and everything, so if you don't have an operating system installed, your computer won't boot anymore.

***Additionally***, if you wish to reinstall the Windows 7 OS in your computer, the Install process offers Advanced options for deleting, formatting and creating new partitions in your hard drive at the very moment that you are installing.

For that purpose you will find a screen like this:

[image]

On which you can click on the "Drive options (advanced)" link in order to see this:

[image]

*Note that both images are from different sources, the last one shows you several partitions, which can be erased by using the tools provided.*

You may wish to look for an install step-by-step process/manual for Windows 7 if that's what you wish. Take in consideration that if you wish to install Ubuntu again, you will have several options in the partitioner when installing, which includes but not limits to "Use the entire disk", as shown in this partitioning tool screenshot:

[image]

Please let us know if you require further information on what you wish to do.

Good luck!

- *All images from the net.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and clean up all your Hard Disk. After that, your computer will be clean and you will be free to install any OS that you want.